# Strip string content except specific HTML element and its content

Tags: php, regex, expression

I´m looking for a PHP solution to strip the content of a string except a specific HTML element and its content.

Here is an example:

Original string

```
<span class="vmshipment_name">Fragtmand</span>
<span class="vmshipment_description">Vi leverer i hele landet. Alle produkter fra Jabo, herunder hytter, havehegn osv. transporteres fra Sverige.<br>
Leveringstiden er ca. 12-18 dage.</span>
```

Now, this is what I want to extract

```
<span class="vmshipment_name">Fragtmand</span>
```

So, Im looking for a PHP expression to strip/remove everything in a string except the span-element with class name "vmshipment_name"

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: try this library http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class:

```
<?php

$html = '<span class="vmshipment_name">Fragtmand</span>
<span class="vmshipment_description">Vi leverer i hele landet. Alle produkter fra Jabo, herunder hytter, havehegn osv. transporteres fra Sverige.<br>
Leveringstiden er ca. 12-18 dage.</span>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='vmshipment_name']");

echo $dom->saveHTML($results->item(0));
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/2ed46e899ec03c):

```
<span class="vmshipment_name">Fragtmand</span>
```

Comment: That did the trick perfectly, and this will no doubt come in handy for me in the future. So, thx man

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what other use cases you have. For the simple example you've given, I would use a regular expression. For a more general class of use cases, you will probably want to use a DOM parser, like [PHP DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you should be escaping and sanitizing your inputs.

You can also use preg_match instead, if you only want to match one. The below code matches them all.

```
   <?php
        $test_string = '<span class="vmshipment_name">Fragtmand</span>
            <span class="vmshipment_description">Vi leverer i hele landet. Alle   produkter fra Jabo, herunder hytter, havehegn osv. transporteres fra Sverige.<br>
            Leveringstiden er ca. 12-18 dage.</span>';

        preg_match_all('@<span.+class="vmshipment_name".+</span>@', $test_string, $matches);

        print_r($matches);
   ?>
```

---

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span class="vmshipment_name">Fragtmand</span>
        )

)
```